# Sending a signal to a running Python Script

Tags: python, bash, signals

I have a python program that plays a video (using OpenCV). This runs concurrently with a couple of other programs - and based on some conditions, I want to be able to send the python script running the video a signal that tells it to stop, play, pause, etc. I currently have something that listens to keystrokes, and if a certain key is pressed, it executes a certain action.

But, I cannot have a user keep sending keystroke signals. I tried to think of some way to have the bash script I am running (that will, by the way, be the medium through which I send these signals to said python script) send the keystroke messages through a little hack using `wmcntrl` and `xdotool`, but it is really not working as intended.

So, what is the Python way of having a bash script send a signal like "Pause", "Play", "Take Screenshot", etc? I am kinda lost...

Thank you

Comment: really not sure it's the best way, but you could make a FIFO from the bash script, shoot your signals as string within ('PAUSE', 'STOP', ...) and just read the fifo in the python soft..

Comment: @Arount  how would I use queues to receive these signals? The signal class doens't really provide that kind of support... not sure what else to use... there must be a way to do this????